# reordering date picker spinners - android 4.2.2

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using default android date picker (4.2.2). Just like in settings of any default android (emulator or nexus) , if the user changes the date format , I have to change the order of spinners in date picker.

Can someone please tell me how it can be done.

There is a private  method reOrderSpinners in DatePicker class. But how can I use this method to change the order of spinners based on date format.

Thanks in advance.